# Teradata SQL Cumulative Sum over date from another table

Tags: sql, join, teradata, cumulative-sum

The case In brief; the customer subscribes to a monthly service, the renewal date would be any day within the month, not just the month beginning, and he could also renew early or late (before/after the due date) then he consumes a from his quota bundle on daily basis and perhaps he could consume all his bundle quota befroe renewal date. So I need to calculate the `Running Total` for `Consumption_Value` based on the service renewal date, not the calendar date
I have two tables:

- the First one: `Consumption_T` that holds the info for a subscriber daily consumption on specific offer IDs, like the below sample

```
|Subs_ID|Consumption_Date|Offer_ID|Quota|Consumption_Value|
|-------+----------------+--------+-----+-----------------|
|12345  |22-01-2021      |123     |140  |1                |
|12345  |23-01-2022      |123     |140  |3                |
|12345  |24-01-2023      |123     |140  |5                |
|12345  |25-01-2022      |123     |140  |3                |
|12345  |26-01-2023      |123     |140  |6                |
|12345  |27-01-2024      |123     |140  |4                |
|…      |…               |…       |…    |…                |
|12345  |15-02-2021      |123     |140  |10               |
|12345  |22-02-2021      |123     |140  |4                |
```

- The other table `Renewal_T` is for the renewal dates like the one below:

```
|Subs_ID|Renewal_Date|Offer_ID|
|-------+------------+--------|
|12345  |22-01-2021  |123     |
|12345  |22-02-2021  |123     |
|12345  |18-03-2022  |123     |
|12345  |19-04-2022  |123     |
|12345  |15-05-2023  |123     |
|12345  |16-06-2023  |123     |
```

The desired output will be like the below

```
|Subs_ID|Consumption_Date|Offer_ID|Quota|Consumption_Value|Running Total|
|-------+----------------+--------+-----+-----------------+-------------|
|12345  |22-01-2021      |123     |140  |1                |1            |
|12345  |23-01-2022      |123     |140  |3                |4            |
|12345  |24-01-2023      |123     |140  |5                |9            |
|12345  |25-01-2022      |123     |140  |3                |12           |
|12345  |26-01-2023      |123     |140  |6                |18           |
|12345  |27-01-2024      |123     |140  |4                |22           |
|…      |…               |…       |…    |…                |…            |
|12345  |15-02-2021      |123     |140  |10               |140          |
|12345  |22-02-2021      |123     |140  |4                |4            |
```

Comment: Your output seems to have nothing to do with `renewal_date`. It looks like a straight running sum using `consumption_date`.

Comment: What if running total prior to date is 135 (so 5 remaining) and consumption for this day is 10?

Comment: @Andrew I need the ```renewal_date``` because the quota renews based on this date, and not every month begenning.

Answer (score 0):

The data model is not very clear; does the renewal period apply to a **Subs_Id**, or to **Subs_Id**+**Offer_Id** combination? Are you sure the years of Consumption_date and Renewal_Date examples are correct (2022, 2023, etc); these are not coherent. If I assume that the primary key to renewals is Subs_Id+Offer_Id+Renewal_Date, then this would produce what you want:

```sql
 select T1.*, 
      sum(Consumption_Value) 
         over (partition by T1.Subs_Id, T1.Offer_ID, SubsPeriod.RenewalDate_From 
               order by Consumption_Date 
               rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as "Running Total"
from Consumption_T as T1
     
    inner join
    (select 
          Subs_Id
        , Offer_Id
        , Renewal_Date as RenewalDate_From
        , LEAD(Renewal_Date-1,1,date '3000-01-01') 
               over (partition by Subs_ID, Offer_Id order by Renewal_Date) as RenewalDate_To
    from Renewal_T
    ) SubsPeriod
    on SubsPeriod.Subs_Id=T1.Subs_Id
    and SubsPeriod.Offer_Id=T1.Offer_Id
    and T1.Consumption_Date 
        between SubsPeriod.RenewalDate_From and SubsPeriod.RenewalDate_To
order by T1.Subs_Id, T1.OffeR_Id, Consumption_date
```

Provided that the example dates are all 2021.

The sub query SubsPeriod derives the renewal periods (with from & to dates, inclusive), and we then join the consumption data to these periods, expecting that the consumption date is within the renewal period. We then calculate a running total for each subs_id, offer_id, renewal period.

Comment: Did this answer help?